# Getting a random emoji/character from a unicode string

Tags: unicode, f#

My goal is to get a random emoticon, from a list, in F#.

I started with this:

```
let pickOne (icons: string) : char = icons.[Helpers.random.Next(icons.Length)]
let happySymbols = ""
let sadSymbols   = ""
```

that doesn't work because:

```
"".Length
```

is returning 44 as length returns the number of chars in a string, which is not working well with unicode characters. 
I can't just divide by 2 because I may add some single byte characters in the string at some point.

Indexing doesn't work either:

```
let a = ""
a.[0]
```

will not return  but I get some unknown character symbol.

so, plan B was: let's make this an array instead of a string:

```
let a = [| ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; ''; '' |]
```

this is not compiling, I'm getting:

> Parse error Unexpected quote symbol in binding. Expected '|]' or other token.

why is that?

anyhow, I can make a list of strings and get it to work, but I'm curious: is there a "proper" way to make the first one work and take a random unicode character from a unicode string?

Comment: Try replacing single quotes with double quotes. You'll get a string array of emoticons.

Comment: yes, that's what I wrote in the last line of my question; I know I can make an array of strings, but my question is why it doesn't work with chars

Comment: It will work if you do e.g. icons.Substring(2, 2) for the second icon.

Comment: @BentTranberg It won't work if there's any non-emoji character in the mix.

Comment: I know. That's why I didn't want to base an answer on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All strings in .NET are 16-bit unicode strings.
That's the definition of `char`:

> Represents a character as a UTF-16 code unit.

All characters take up the minimum encoding size (2 bytes for UTF-16), up to as many bytes as required. Emojis don't fit in 2 bytes, so they align to 4 bytes, or 2 chars.

So what's the solution? align(4) all the things! (insert GCC joke here).

First we convert everything into `UTF32`:

```
let utf32 (source: string) =
    Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF32, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(source))
```

Then we can pick and choose any "character":

```
let pick (arr: byte[]) index = 
    Encoding.UTF32.GetString(arr, index * 4, 4)
```

Test:

```
let happySymbols = "YTHO"

pick (utf32 happySymbols) 0;;
val it : string = ""

> pick (utf32 happySymbols) 22;;
val it : string = "Y"
```

For the actual length, just div by 4.

```
let surpriseMe arr =
    let rnd = Random()
    pick arr (rnd.Next(0, arr.Length / 4))
```

Hmmm

```
> surpriseMe (utf32 happySymbols);;
val it : string = ""
```

Comment: Hey @Thomas, here's [a good primer on unicode](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Answer (score 4):

Asti's answer works for your purpose, but I wasn't too happy about where we landed on this. I guess I got hung up in the word "proper" in the answer. After a lot of research in various places, I got curious about the method [String.EnumerateRunes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.enumeraterunes?view=netcore-3.1), which again lead me to the type [Rune](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.rune?view=netcore-3.1). The documentation for that type is particularly enlightening about proper string handling, and what's in a Unicode UTF-8 string in .NET. I also experimented in LINQPad, and got this.

```
let dump x = x.Dump()
let runes = "abcABCæøåÆØÅ₅茨茧茦茥".EnumerateRunes().ToArray()
runes.Length |> dump
// 20
runes |> Array.iter (fun rune -> dump (string rune))
// a b c A B C æ ø å Æ Ø Å    ₅ 茨 茧 茦 茥
dump runes
// see screenshot
let smiley = runes.[13].ToString()
dump smiley
//
```

[image]

Comment: I had no idea about the Rune type but it looks like it could be the way to go since the implementation, in my side, should have to know about the size of each symbol, etc. I will experiment with that tomorrow!

Comment: This is a nice find! Seems to be an addition to .NET Core 3.0.